# How to log the time it takes for a thread to die on a swing EditorPane each second?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am working on a GUI program that has a "start" button and when pressed it starts a botThread and the start button turns into a stop button. Pretty simple so far.

Now when I press on stop, I want my EditorPane to look like this:

```
19:10:40.027 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  bot.StartStopListener - Stopping bot...
19:10:41.096 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  bot.StartStopListener - Stopping bot...(1s)
19:10:42.099 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  bot.StartStopListener - Stopping bot...(2s)
19:10:43.158 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  bot.StartStopListener - Stopping bot...(3s)
19:10:44.160 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  bot.StartStopListener - Stopping bot...(4s)
19:10:45.106 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  bot.StartStopListener - Bot stopped
```

The above output is from my console where everything works fine. Every second it prints a new line.

On my EditorPane, there are no lines printed every second. They get printed all at once when the botThread is dead.

Why is that the case?
Here is the code that gets executed when the stop button is pressed:

```
stop = true;
settingsPanel.getStartButton().setEnabled(false);
LOGGER.info("Stopping bot...");

//wait for the bot thread to die
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    long last = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int seconds = 0;
    while(botThread.isAlive()){
        try {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(now-last > 1000){
                seconds++;
                last = now;
                LOGGER.info(String.format("Stopping bot...(%ds)", seconds));
            }
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("BotThread Interrupted");
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
    LOGGER.info("Bot stopped");
});
```

For the logging on the Editorpane, there is this line in my logback.xml:

```
<appender name="TEXTAREA" class="io.logging.EditorPaneAppender"/>
```

I do not know if this is necessary, but also here is my EditorPaneAppender class:

```
public class EditorPaneAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    private final static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    public final static JEditorPane editorPane;

    static{
        editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(final ILoggingEvent e) {
        String txt = editorPane.getText();
        txt = txt.replace("<html>","")
                .replace("</html>","")
                .replace("<body>","")
                .replace("</body>","") // im too lazy to do it properly
                .replace("<head>","")
                .replace("</head>","")
                .replace("<p style=\"margin-top: 0\">","")
                .replace("</p>","");


        String colored_level_template = switch (e.getLevel().toInt()) {
            case 20000 -> //info
                    "<span style=\"color:2259E3FF\">%s</span>";
            case 30000 -> //warn
                    "<span style=\"color:E38E0AFF\">%s</span>";
            case 40000 -> //error
                    "<span style=\"color:E71019FF\">%s</span>";
            default -> "";
        };

        editorPane.setText(txt + String.format("<span>[%s]</span> %s - %s"
                , sdf.format(new Date(e.getTimeStamp()))
                , String.format(colored_level_template, e.getLevel())
                , e.getFormattedMessage()) + "<br>");
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use a while loop with a Thread.sleep(...) on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This  prevents the GUI from repainting itself until the loop is finished. Instead you can use the looping/sleeping code in a `SwingWorker` and "publish" results for display in the editor pane. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about SwingWorkers. Got it to work with a worker!

Comment: @smilly Good to hear you solved it. Now you can post and accept an Answer to your own Question for posterity.